# How to Transpose table in redshift?

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift, transpose

Is there some better way, to transpose a table in redshift, other than taking it out in Pandas and getting things done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using below query. But the below query would be helpful, if the **number of rows per group is a constant value**

```
SELECT col1, 
       Split_part(col_values, ',', 1) col_value1, 
       Split_part(col_values, ',', 2) col_value2, 
       Split_part(col_values, ',', 3) col_value3 
FROM  (SELECT col1, 
              Listagg(col2, ',') 
                within GROUP (ORDER BY col2) col_values 
       FROM   (SELECT col1, 
                      col2 
               FROM   table1) derived_table1
       GROUP  BY col1) derived_table2
```

**Note: The above query will be used if you have same number of rows per group or if you know the maximum number of rows per group.**

Answer (score 0):

Transposing data in SQL is never a fun task. However if the data does fit in memory in pandas this package might make the process smoother.

https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift

An example of how to do this is as follows:

pip install pandas-redshift

```
import pandas_redshift as pr

# Provide your redshift credentials and connect to redshift
pr.connect_to_redshift(dbname = <dbname>,
                        host = <host>,
                        port = <port>,
                        user = <user>,
                        password = <password>)

# This next step reads the data from redshift to your python session
data = pr.redshift_to_pandas('select * from gawronski.nba_shots_log')

# Transpose the DataFrame
data_transposed = data.transpose()

# Provide S3 credentials 
# (data goes to S3 then redshift so an S3 bucket is necessary)
pr.connect_to_s3(aws_access_key_id = <aws_access_key_id>,
                aws_secret_access_key = <aws_secret_access_key>,
                bucket = 'my-bucket-name',
                # this is and optional parameter:
                subdirectory = 'subdirectory-in-the-bucket')

# Write the transposed DataFrame back to redshift
pr.pandas_to_redshift(data_frame = data_transposed, 
             redshift_table_name = 'public.my_transposed_table'
```

**Edit: Updated to avoid providing a link only answer.**

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.